# Interdependent Network visualisation

Tags: r, visualization, networkx, muxviz

I've come across some questions when using muxViz (the package developed by Manlio De Domenico with R and GNU Octave -- thanks for developing this!).

I was trying to create and visualise an interdependent network graph, but when I imported the example file the GUI froze. I'm not sure which part I've got wrong.
I followed the tutorial(http://muxviz.net/tutorial.php) and created the multilayer edges. It is supposed to be a 2-layer interdependent network. Node 1-4 are investors (Layer 1) and Node 5-7 are brokers (Layer 2).

```
1 1 3 1 2
1 1 6 1 1
2 1 4 1 0.5
2 1 5 2 1
3 1 7 2 2
4 1 3 1 1
5 2 6 2 7.6
5 2 7 2 6.7
7 2 6 2 2.2
```

The edge file is currently saved as *.txt* file. I saw the edges are in *.edges* format in some examples but I don't know how to create that file, so I don't know if that is the problem.

Thanks for helping with my questions!

PS. The graph is supposed to be like this (I drew manually)

[image]

Comment: Why is this question tagged with R?

Comment: @G5W, though not clear in the question, I found that muxViz requires R-3.0.2 or newer (ref: http://muxviz.net/tutorial.php). (And though the [github page](https://github.com/manlius/muxViz/tree/master) says that it has migrated from octave to R, it still says that it also requires octave.)

Comment: Hi @G5W yes this package is developed based on R and Octave, but it has got a well-developed GUI so the users don't have write codes by themselves. I tagged it with R was because I'm not sure how to create and check the .edges file. I checked online and it seems R can read this type of file so I would like to know how.